# RC Plane Radio using the Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-2.x, serial-port, raspberry-pi

This python code is for a homemade RC plane radio using the Raspberry Pi and a USB joystick. It sends values over serial to DSM2/X module for RC planes and other RC vehicles. This Python code is modified from [codeforge's](https://www.youtube.com/user/codeforge) video "CustomRC with raspberry and joystick usb" with many improvements by me. feedback on the python code would be great as i rushed the modifications that add expo, channel reversing and channel offset.

```
########################################################################################################################
# This short code take input from a usb joystick ( I use microsoft sidewinder) and send it through serial
# to a DSM2 module to control all kind of helicopter, multicopter or spektrum compatible devices. This code
# must be run in raspbian with raspberry pi (I use a raspberry pi 2 B). You need to modified rPi speed as following:
# 1 - remove all "ttyAMA0" from /boot/cmdline.txt
# 2 - add the following lines to the end of /boot/config.txt:
#       dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#       dtparam=i2c1=on
#       init_uart_clock=3255000
#       init_uart_baud=115200
#       dtparam=uart0_clkrate=3000000
#
# 3 - reboot raspberry pi
# 4 - install python modules pygame and pyserial
# 5 - power on the spektrum receiver or spektrum device in BIND mode (led flashing)
# 6 - run this code with root privileges: sudo python joystick.py
# 7 - wait the binding complete and enjoy :)
#
# PLEASE CONNECT DSM2 MODULE VCC (red or power) TO 3.3v AND NOT 5V OR YOU WILL BURN IT!
# THEN CONNECT NEGATIVE TO NEGATIVE AND SIGNAL PIN OF DSM2 MODULE TO TX PIN ON RASPBERRY PI
# NO NEED TO CONNECT RX PIN SO YOU NEED TO CONNECT JUCT 3 PIN OR CABLES
#
# For any info contact me at codeforge@hotmail.com
#
#
# Copyright (C) <2016>  <Guido Berbacchi>
# Modified <10/11/16> <Ethan Johnston>
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
########################################################################################################################

import pygame
from time import sleep
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 115200)


def sendDSM2():  # function to send data to dsm2/x module
    ser.write(DSM2_Header)
    ser.write(DSM2_Channel)
    sleep(0.014)

def arduino_map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):  # map function as arduino map()
    return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) // (in_max - in_min) + out_min   

def reverse_val(valinput, in_minval, in_maxval):
    return (in_maxval - valinput) + in_minval

def apply_expo(axis_val, factor):
    factor = reverse_val(factor, 0, 100)
    factor = factor / 100
    return (1 - factor) * axis_val * axis_val * axis_val + factor * axis_val

# Global Variable and static
DSM2_Header = bytearray(b'\x98\x01') # header to bind
DSM2_Channel = bytearray(b'\x18\x00\x05\xFF\x09\xFF\x0D\xFF\x10\xAA\x14\xAA')
DSM2_CHANNELS = 6
EPA = 300 #300
EPAGAS = 180 #180
fineBinding = 30
i = 0
val = 512
BExit = 0

#reverse channels
ch0rev = False #throttle
ch1rev = True  #roll
ch2rev = False  #pitch
ch3rev = True #yaw
ch4rev = False #gear
ch5rev = False #aux

#epo for channels
ch0expo = 0  #throttle
ch1expo = 20 #roll
ch2expo = 20 #pitch
ch3expo = 20 #yaw

#Trims
ch0offset = 0 #throttle
ch1offset = 0 #roll
ch2offset = 0 #pitch
ch3offset = 0 #yaw
ch4offset = 0 #gear
ch5offset = 0 #aux

print ("Binding")

while fineBinding >= 0:

    sendDSM2()
    #print "binding"
    sleep(0.1)
    fineBinding = fineBinding - 1

print ("Binding end")

sleep(1)


# change header to send input
DSM2_Header[0] = '\x18';


# pygame initialization to read joystick input
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.joystick.init()
joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
joystick.init()


while BExit == 0:

 pygame.event.get() 

 roll = joystick.get_axis(0) 
 pitch = joystick.get_axis(1)
 yaw = joystick.get_axis(2)
 gas = joystick.get_axis(3)


 if ch0rev == True:
  gas = reverse_val(gas, -1, 1)

 if ch1rev == True:
  roll = reverse_val(roll, -1, 1)

 if ch2rev == True:
  pitch = reverse_val(pitch, -1, 1)

 if ch3rev == True:
  yaw = reverse_val(yaw, -1, 1)

 roll = apply_expo(roll, ch1expo)
 pitch = apply_expo(pitch, ch2expo)
 yaw = apply_expo(yaw, ch3expo)
 gas = apply_expo(gas, ch0expo)

 hat = joystick.get_hat(0)
 BLeft = joystick.get_button( 2 )
 BRight = joystick.get_button( 3 )

 if BLeft == 1:
  ch3offset -= 4
  print("Yaw Trim: {}".format(ch3offset))

 if BRight == 1:
  ch3offset += 4
  print("Yaw Trim: {}".format(ch3offset))

 if hat[1] == 1:
  ch2offset += 4
  print("pitch Trim: {}".format(ch2offset))

 if hat[1] == -1:
  ch2offset -= 4
  print("pitch Trim: {}".format(ch2offset))

 if hat[0] == 1:
  ch1offset += 4
  print("roll Trim: {}".format(ch1offset))

 if hat[0] == -1:
  ch1offset -= 4
  print("roll Trim: {}".format(ch1offset))

 BExit = 0

 while (i < DSM2_CHANNELS):
    if i == 0:   #throttle
     val = int(arduino_map(gas, -1.0, 1.0, 1023, 0+EPAGAS)) #723 - 300
     val = val + ch0offset
     #print ("gas",val)
    elif i == 1:   #roll
     val = int(arduino_map(roll, -1.0, 1.0, 1023-EPA, 0+EPA)) #723 - 300
     val = val + ch1offset
     #print ("roll",val)     
    elif i == 2:   #pitch
     val = int(arduino_map(pitch, -1.0, 1.0, 1023-EPA, 0+EPA)) #723 - 300
     val = val + ch2offset
     #print ("pitch",val)
    elif i == 3:   # yaw
     val = int(arduino_map(yaw, -1.0, 1.0, 1023-EPA, 0+EPA)) #723 - 300
     val = val + ch3offset
    elif i == 4:
     val = 512
     val = val + ch4offset
    elif i == 5:
     val = 512
     val = val + ch5offset
    else:   #the remaining channels set to half
     val = 512

    if val > 1023:
     val = 1023
    if val < 0:
     val = 0
    (high, low) = (val // 0x100, val % 0x100)
    DSM2_Channel[i*2] = (i<<2) | high
    DSM2_Channel[i*2+1] = low

    i+=1
    sendDSM2()
    clock.tick(135)


 i=0

pygame.quit ()
```

Comment: So you got this code originally from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gv3VH009A8Y) video? Unfortunately I can't find the code. But, what licence did you obtain the original under, and are you legally allowed to re-licence it to CC-BY-SA?

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold until the aforementioned licensing concern is resolved.

Comment: i asked for permission

Comment: to use and modify and redistribute

Comment: the license is a GNU General Public License

Comment: i added the license file on. everything should be good